# :set title in vim doesn't work in gnome terminal

Tags: gnome, 14.04, gnome-terminal, vim

I need to be able to see what I'm working on. On my sisters laptop using unity, `:set title` sets the title, but on my GNOME desktop with GNOME Terminal 3.10.2 it doesn't do anything.

I can set the title with the command `gnome-terminal --title="SOME TITLE"`

I can set the title in the GNOME Terminal preferences menu, and I do know that I have set the option to replace the initial title.

Comment: Is she using the same version and do you both have the same settings?  What is the result that you want?

Comment: Yeah shes using a different version. I think this might just be a bug in the newer gnome-terminal. I found a workaround though. Posting it below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a work around for anyone who may be having the same issue:

add `:silent !echo -en "\033]0;%:t\a"` to your `.vimrc`

This changes the title to `%:t` which is the file name without the full path.